# Reverse of Deduction Theorem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Why is it "easy to see" that if $S \vdash (A\to B)$ then $S \cup\{A\} \vdash B$?

Comment: Hello Kevin, you have asked 28 questions and you have only accepted half of them. Maybe you should start accepting the answers that people have kindly helped you to solve. This way people will be helping you more often.

Comment: Who says that it *is* each to see? It seems that there is some context behind the question - you should include that context.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is not so easy to see!

The only axiom we have is the original single axiom DDpDqrDDtDttDDsqDDpsDps, and our only rule of inference other than uniform substitution is

{D$\alpha$D$\beta$$\gamma$, $\alpha$} $\vdash$ $\gamma$.

This "if S⊢(A→B), then S∪{A}⊢B" involves $\rightarrow$.  I'll rewrite that as:
"if **S**$\vdash$Cab, then **S** **∪** {a} $\vdash$b."  Thus, using the definition

Cpq := DpDqq, we want to show that:

"if **S**$\vdash$DaDbb, then **S** **∪** {a} $\vdash$b."

Suppose that we've proved DaDbb.  This means that in the rule above we can substitute $\alpha$ with "a", $\beta$ with "b", and $\gamma$ with "b" yielding:

{DaDbb, a} $\vdash$ b.  Now from that since we have $\vdash$DaDbb, and "a" consists of a hypothesis, $\vdash$b.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\langle\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\ldots,\varphi_n\rangle$ be a proof of $(A\to B)$ from $S$: $\varphi_n$ is $(A\to B)$, and each $\varphi_k$ with $k<n$ either is in $S$, is an axiom, or follows from earlier statements in the list by one of your inference rules. Then $\langle\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n=(A\to B),A,B\rangle$ is a proof of $B$ from $S\cup\{A\}$: the presence of $A$ in the list is justified by the fact that $A\in S\cup\{A\}$, and $B$ follows from $(A\to B)$ and $A$ by modus ponens, which is surely one of your rules of inference.

Comment: "by modus ponens, which is surely one of your rules of inference."  Well you never know... the author could be learning logic from an intellectual descendant of Jean Nicod, Jean Porte http://home.utah.edu/~nahaj/logic/structures/systems/pc-porte.html or the still living Lloyd Humberstone http://jigpal.oxfordjournals.org/content/16/5/431.short.

Answer (score 2):

The statement $S\vdash (A\to B)$ means that there is a formal proof using the assumptions in $S$ (as well as standard axioms, and rules of inference including *modus ponens*) which ends with the line $A\to B$.

Take this proof and append two more lines:

> $A$ (assumption)
>   $B$ (modus ponens from the previous two lines).

You now have a formal proof using the assumptions in $S$, together with another assumption $A$, and ending with the formula $B$.  The existence of such a proof is exactly what is asserted by the statement $S\cup\{A\}\vdash B$.